# How to pass the cubes after defeating Gernot the Spire?

Tags: valdis-story-abyssal-city

After defeating Gernot the Spire there is some spiky cubes on the right side of the room.
I don't know how to pass them or what item/spell I should find to be able to do it.
So basicly i'm stuck there because the door from the left side is blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defeating Gernot should have given you a new type of magic: **Void**

The side magic for void is a teleportation spell.  It fires a slow moving ball of energy.  Activating the magic again will teleport you to the energy ball's location.

Fire the magic spell through the cubes, and then activate it again on the other side to teleport past them.